# Is it possible to include a hyper link in Json text fieled

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have below Json request body which is sent to a REST service. It will take the content part and send that as an email. In email I want to see href link hide with given link name.

```
{"content":"Do search to identify few issues.\n\n <a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/html/\">Only this part needs to be displayed as link</a>"}
```

If i give like above entire string is getting displayed. How can I make href part to be hidden and only **Only this part needs to be displayed as link** is dispalyed along with other string using java.

Comment: You mean on a web page? And you mean you want it to be actually interpreted as html?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I need to call a rest service with above mentioned json and content text is send in email and when it displayed in email it should be displayed in hyperlink

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I need to call a REST service with taht request body.

Comment: How the string is displayed after being sent to the REST service is out of your control. Unless *you* are coding that REST service, in which case I suggest you edit your question to give a bit more context.