# How to include a hyper link in json text filed in rest response

Tags: java, json, rest

I need to send a response body with text filed. This field will have some text and a hyperlink to a URL. How to define a hyper link in the text filed of response body.

```
{
"content":"This page give more info about tech development \n\n  <a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/html/\">Only this part needs to be displayed as link</a>"
}
```

If i give like this when i interpret this content in Web application and print in my page I can see like below.

**This page give more info about tech development

https://www.w3schools.com/html/\">Only this part needs to be displayed as link**

But I want something like

**This page give more info about tech development

 Only this part needs to be displayed as link (This should be displayed as link)**

Note: My rest service which create this body is based on Spring Boot and using Jackson library.

Comment: Uhm... how is this question different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794450/is-it-possible-to-include-a-hyper-link-in-json-text-fieled) other one of yours?

Comment: Anyway, as I said in the other question, this doesn't depend on how the JSON is built, but only on how you render it on the page/email/whatever.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca when i send response like above in rendering app I can see complete text. So I don't know where to fix this in server side or client side or the body which I am sending is correct format.

Comment: Again, you need to fix the way your *render* it. This has nothing to do with that json, just with the string in `content` and how you display it. So please post the code that actually *uses* that string.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have understood the issue and made the correct fix in the rendering part of it